# BURSTIO components?

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a BURSTIO source that I would like to make a Waveform with in Redhawk. However, I noticed that all the components that come with Redhawk and GNUHawk are BULKIO. To my understanding, BULKIO and BURSTIO components cannot be used together, so therefore my BURSTIO source can't do much with the stock Redhawk components.

I have two questions:

1. Do I have to re-implement all of the components I want to use into BURSTIO, or is there a way to use BURSTIO and BULKIO components together?
2. Why doesn't Redhawk provide BURSTIO components?

---

**UPDATE**: For the most part, I understand the difference between BulkIO and BurstIO. I am still trying to figure out **if it is possible to use BulkIO components on data provided by a BurstIO source**. My waveform reads data from a BurstIO source component, and because of this it seems that I cannot use any of the Redhawk or GNUHawk components. I just want to make sure this is the case before I spend the time to implement the components I need as BurstIO. Maybe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of Redhawk IO and should not be using a BurstIO source? Any feedback is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BURSTIO and BULKIO are two different interfaces meant to solve two different problems (see chapter 15 of the manual).  One of the needs for BURSTIO is illustrated through the optimization charts in the manual.   Essentially when you use a pushPacket on a very small chunks of data (say 100 samples per push), the performance effects are dramatic.

Second BURSTIO assumes pushSRI is done every pushPacket which is not true for BULKIO (only necessary for changes to the SRI).  This is because burst traffic cannot be assumed to be the same (at least BURSTIO does not assume that) push to push.

Is there a specific component you have in mind as a candidate for a BUSRTIO component?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking at chapter 15 of the manual but I don't see optimization charts, would you able to point me to where they are? 

After reading chapter 15, it seems like one of the differences is that BURSTIO can handle variable length data. The source for my Waveform sends variable length complex data. Since it's variable length, I needed to use BURSTIO (the SRI changes for every packet as well). However, using BURSTIO is very limiting because I can't use any of the Redhawk components, such as demodulation and filter decimating. Do I have to re-implement these for BURSTIO?

Comment: @five_dollar_shake optimization charts are in Appendix H.

Comment: I found the document, thanks. So is it possible to use BULKIO and BURSTIO components together? Thanks again for your response.

Comment: You cannot use BURSTIO to send and BUKLIO to receive.   The interfaces have to be the same to make the remote call (remember each component is its own process).  If performance isn't a huge consideration you can use BULKIO to do sri changes every pushpacket AND it doesn't actually matter if ever pushPacket the size of the vector is different.  It just means you have to handle that properly  on the other end and you can have performance issues when the packet sizes get small and the custom Sri keywords is large.

Comment: Performance isn't a consideration at this point, I like that idea. Is it possible for me to use BulkIO on variable length data?